# Python Telebot Удалить inline клавиатуру, если отправлено сообщение

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Телеграм бот отправляет 2 кнопки, но если пользователь отправит сообщение, то кнопки так и останутся. Мне нужно что бы после отправки кнопок, если пользователь не нажмет на них, а отправит любое сообщение, эти кнопки скрывались. Я понимаю что нужно использовать bot.edit_message_text. Но не знаю  как проверить, отправил ли сообщение пользователь.

```
keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
url = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Ссылка', url='https://')
keyboard.add(url)
button =types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='кнопка',callback_data='yes')
keyboard.add(button);
bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Сообщение', reply_markup=keyboard)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == 'yes':
        print(call.message.text)
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda c:True, content_types=['text'])#этот блок выполнится если юзер отправит боту сообщение
def info_message(message):
    bot.edit_message_reply_markup(message.chat.id, message_id = message.message_id-1, reply_markup = '')# удаляем кнопки у последнего сообщения
```

Как-то так

Comment: а, как написать универсальный вариант: чтобы работал, если пользователь напишет сообщение или нажмёт на кнопку?

Comment: после нажатия кнопки (обработка callback) изменяйте сообщение удаляя кнопку(и)

Answer (score 0):

Надо записывать id сообщения с кнопками и id пользователя
Как только приходит любое сообщение с этого id пользователя - удаляем кнопки у сообщения с данным id (bot.edit_message_text)
Или я как-то не так понял вопрос?

Answer (score -1):

```
bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Текст нашей кнопки", reply_markup=None)
```

Comment: Сверх изи! Читайте документацию

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]